# Margin inside of a DIV

Tags: html, css, class, web, margin

I'm trying to margin some text inside of a div and I do not want to margin the whole page, I want the margin to start from the div. That is because I've made the website fit for people that have at least 800 x 600 resolution screens and if I would've margined the whole page the website would've looked different for people with other resolutions than 1920 x 1080 (My resolution).

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

p
{
    display:inline;
}

.logo
{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(images/Logo.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logobg
{
    background-color: #0e1216;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 800px;
}

.navBarBtn
{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100 %;
    height: 25px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<!--Logo & Navigation Bar-->
<div class="logobg">
<div class="logo">

<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn1"> Hem </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn2"> Om Oss </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn3"> Referenser </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn4"> Partners </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn5"> Kontakt </p>

</div>
</div>
```

And here's the website so you can take a look at it yourselves. [Website URL](http://undertak.se)

Answer (score 4):

Use the padding css property of the container (div) instead. Padding is the space inside and border of the element, while margin is the space outside the border of the element.

Check out [box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Comment: Could you give me an example, I tried to change the margin for padding but I do not see any changes.

Comment: You can add something like "padding:20px" to the style of the div that contains the text

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can use fewer classes for your navigation buttons. Using a Float:Left in that css class will line them up horizontally as long as the screen or containing box is wide enough to fit, otherwise it will start a second line underneath. You mentioned that you would like the site optimized for someone with a screen at least 800px wide. Because of that I also suggest you add a min-width:800px in addition to the width:100% in your container class (logobg). If you simply leave the width at 100%, someone using a smaller screen will have the menu shrink and realign a bit and your buttons won't stay all horizontal. Please see the code below:

**HTML**

```
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Hem </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Om Oss </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Referenser </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Partners </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Kontakt </p>
```

**CSS**

```
.logobg {
background-color: #0e1216;
width: 100%;
min-width: 800px;
height: 60px;
}

.navBarBtn {
float:left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 15px;
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Allright, thanks for the answer but this still doesn't solve the problem with the margin part. I'll let you take a look at how the website looks like live: www.undertak.se ; As you can see it doesn't look very good. I want the text that is located on the top left to show up after the logo.

Comment: @kemkoi Ah ok I didn't completely understand what you were looking for. In that case I believe you probably do not want the navigation buttons inside of the div that uses your logo as a background. I would suggest you give the div with the logo a float:left as well so that it becomes part of the "line" with the nav links. So in the css class .logo add float:left; and in the html add and ending </div> right before the navigation links instead of after. Using this way you will probably also need to give the .logo a specific width/height so it doesn't cut anything off or shove your nav away

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but if it is, you could float each "p" element and then add margins between them instead of having them positioned as absolute.

**HTML:**

```
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Hem </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Om Oss </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Referenser </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Partners </p>
<p id="text1" class="navBarBtn"> Kontakt </p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navBarBtn
{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100 %;
    height: 25px;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**http://jsfiddle.net/xakaxsqg/3/